# How to copy an Excel formula without removing logic

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that I am trying to keep dynamic while using the following logic:

```
Cell D500  -  "=D18*D19"
Cell D501  -  "=D20*D21"
Cell D502  -  "=D22*D23"
...
```

I need to keep both the row and column dynamic as I will be copying this over to columns E through SV (~500 columns), but I can't seem to figure out a good way to copy this downwards without it incrementing the row value by 1 instead of 2., or having all sorts of unwanted behavior.

Is there a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use simple references to do that. You need to use the `INDEX()` function for each reference like so:

```dart
=INDEX(D:D,18+(ROW()-500)*2)*INDEX(D:D,18+(ROW()-500)*2+1)
```

Comment: Easier than my `INT()` / `INDIRECT` combo! Nice one

Comment: @piko The golden rule is to never use `INDIRECT()` (or `OFFSET()`) as they are volatile, and can cause slowdowns in large spreadsheets. It's a good habit to get into, even for simple formula and small spreadsheets. Plus most times the formula are simpler using `INDIRECT()` (and usually it's mate, `MATCH()`).

Comment: Amazing - thanks robin and piko!  I've used OFFSET with large spreadsheets for flattening 2D tables dynamically and it does indeed slow things down.  Great solution!

Comment: Oops. The last `INDIRECT()` in my previous comment should have been `INDEX()`!

Comment: Made a slight alteration to the formula as the *2 caused the rows to jump quite a bit using the below but now it's working like a charm ! 
  =INDEX(D:D,18+ROW()-519+ROW(1:1))*INDEX(D:D,18+ROW()-519+ROW(2:2))

Comment: @AdamReed I don't understand what you mean by *"jump quite a bit"*. My formula works perfectly when entered into `D500` and then filled down and right. Yours also works perfectly. What's the issue? The only difference is that yours is a teensy, weensy bit slower as it uses an extra `ROW()` function. (And that you seem to have shifted the the relative position of the source and destination cells.)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using the `INT()` function:

```dart
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INT((ROW()-500)*2)+18,4))*INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INT((ROW()-500)*2)+19,4))
```

There are a few parameters:

- `500`: this is the number where your formula starts, in your case that's cell D500
- `4`: this is the column number (cell D500 is in the 4th column)
- `2`: that's the number of multiplications. If you wanted to multiply 3 items (`D18*D19*D20`), you would need to use `3` instead.
- `18`/`19`: this is the first and second line of your calculations.

I invite you to use the Evaluate button in the Formula tab, to see how it works step-by-step.